# Run java source annotation processing on Scala built class files

Tags: java, scala, gradle, annotations

What I'm looking to do is execute java annotation processing on scala built class files.

I can do this manually by calling javac after building

```
javac -cp ".../.m2/repository/net/java/sezpoz/sezpoz/1.11/sezpoz-1.11.jar:."  \
    -proc:only -processor  net.java.sezpoz.impl.Indexer6 \
    -verbose   mypackage.ScalaUseMyAnnotations$Inner
```

but I want to do it as part of a gradle build. Ultimately I want this to to create Jenkins plugins in Scala and the plugins need to be processed for source annotaion with [sezpoz](https://github.com/jglick/sezpoz). Hence using Gradle.

This is what I have so far but it doesn't work

```
group 'mytest'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'scala'

sourceSets.main.scala.srcDir "src/main/java"
sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = []

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

jar {
    from {
        (configurations.runtime).collect {
            it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
        }
    }
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'mypackage.Main'
    }
}

ext {
    versions = [
            scala     : '2.11.8',
            scalatest : '2.2.6'
    ]
}

task annotate (type: JavaCompile) {
    source = sourceSets.main.output.classesDir
    include 'mypackage.ScalaUseMyAnnotations$Inner'
    classpath = sourceSets.main.compileClasspath
    destinationDir = sourceSets.main.output.classesDir
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }

    println("[annotate] ${sourceSets.main.output.classesDir}")
}

annotate.options.compilerArgs = ['-proc:only',  '-processor',  'net.java.sezpoz.impl.Indexer62',  '-verbose']

task run(type: JavaExec, dependsOn: compileScala) {
    main = 'mypackage.Main'
    classpath sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    classpath configurations.runtime
}

compileScala.doLast {
    tasks.annotate
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'net.java.sezpoz', name: 'sezpoz', version: '1.11'
    runtime group: 'org.scala-lang', name: 'scala-library', version: "$versions.scala"
    compile group: 'org.scala-lang', name: 'scala-library', version: "$versions.scala"
}
```

The problems are that it doesn't seem to find the class files to annotate them, It certainly works manually and it always thinks the task is up to date.

This is the [repo](https://github.com/JeremyMarshall/scala-sezpoz) but Scala likes a recent Java8 compiler

Answer (score 0):

So this is what I did in the end after much thought

```
task annotate(dependsOn:compileScala, type: Exec)  {
    args '-proc:only'
    args '-d'
    args compileJava.destinationDir
    args '-classpath'
    args compileJava.classpath.getAsPath() + java.io.File.pathSeparatorChar + compileJava.destinationDir

    if (logging.level >= LogLevel.INFO) {
        args '-verbose'
    }

    doFirst{
        fileTree(compileScala.destinationDir).each { File file ->
            if(file.path.contains('-')) {
                return
            }
            args file.path.minus(compileScala.destinationDir).minus('.class').substring(1).replaceAll(File.separator,'.')
        }
    }

    executable "javac"
}

compileScala.doLast {annotate.execute()}
```

Its probably not very gradle and I had hoped to use a `JavaCompile` type task.

The main problem is that the classes have to be passed in without the .class extension

I updated the repo in github